# How to make a function accept array of chained modifiers with correct type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to modify a data with chain of function modifiers but with correct typing in typescript. Is this possible?

```
const addA = (data: {}) => {
  return {
    ...data,
    a: "test"
  }
}

const addB = (data: {}) => {
  return {
    ...data,
    b: "test"
  }
}

const updateA = (data: {a:string}) => {
  return {
    ...data,
    a: data.a + " test"
  }
}

const func = <T extends ((data: Record<string, any>) => Record<string, any>)[]>(modifiers: T): unknown => {
  return modifiers.reduce((acc, modifier) => {
    return modifier(acc)
  }, {})
}

console.log(func([addA])) // Pass, Should pass.
console.log(func([addA, addB])) // Pass, Should pass.
console.log(func([addA, addB, updateA])) // Error, Should pass.
console.log(func([updateA])) // Error, Should error. Unexpected runtime undefined value.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQQRgXhgCgXKcBcMA3gL4CU6AfMQLABQMMATgKZQCuTYtDjMAdIJx4ANPT7xCAIigtoU8TBL1ldeqEixECAELoswgsXJUejVhy5m+g-obG9GAI2mz5i1avXhoMdgAdhFlQMbFwjIgJoJgBLMABzEzRqIkULTm5UxwEhcIcJI0N+OBgAahgpGDcoBV5Pem9NGAAzdjBgfQAeABUYFgAPWTAECCwwvEIAJRZQJgRO6Lj4kXgwAE9KCmSYadn5xYSVuHXNgG0AXUpMAFsQBBjmmJYmCEJuskI2gGswEAB3bjbLLmNgZGC3e6PZ4QfisBDsYAsTCYODAYArCEPJ5MLYpRQgyzcTFQpgotFkDwrUgUuheOgaCAgAA2LH4TJA8UwrXamFO2mQ5zIFAA9MKYAAFOAQCArADKAAsQOwmQgYP4pTDGoyWWyOVy2sBefyjkgdIKRWLJdK5Yrlar1dL+Frmaz2ZzuYa+UhkCbdCsAkEBUKYKKYABRJhMEBMG1KlVqjVO+k+F2690G3kB3DBc0hsURqMxmAKuOq56F-gwACqYAG-hmslVTDaUBi1xYfmGLEetdVADc4Ez2KygA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: Your functions always spread input in the output, but your types don't actually reflect this. You could use generics to show this, but that makes the solution below more difficult. As long as the convention is followed that what comes out of the function is at least what went in, the solution below works.

You can use a type parameter to infer the array of functions as a tuple. You can then use a recursive conditional type to build a tuple of what you expect the types of the functions to actually be. You then intersect the type parameter with this validation type. If everything is ok, the inspection is basically a nop, otherwise you will get an error from the intersection:

```
type FunctionArray = Array<(p: any) => any>;
type ValidateChain<T extends FunctionArray , Input = {}, Result extends any[] = []> = 
  T extends [(data: Input) => infer R, ...infer Tail extends FunctionArray] ? ValidateChain<Tail, Input & R, [...Result, T[0]]>:
  T extends [(...p: infer P) => infer R, ...infer Tail extends FunctionArray] ? ValidateChain<Tail, Input & R, [...Result, (data: Input) => R]>:
  Result

type MergeAll<T extends FunctionArray , Input = {}> = 
  T extends [(data: any) => infer R, ...infer Tail extends FunctionArray] ? MergeAll<Tail, R & Input>: Input

const func = <T extends [] | FunctionArray>(modifiers: T & ValidateChain<T>): MergeAll<T> => {
  return (modifiers as T).reduce((acc, modifier) => {
    return modifier(acc)
  }, {}) as MergeAll<T> 
}

let r1 = func([addA]) // Pass
let r2 = func([addA, addB]) // Pass
let r3 = func([addA, addB, updateA]) //Pass.
let r4 = func([addA, addB, updateC]) // Fails
let r5 = func([updateA]) // Fails
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQQRgXhgCgXKcBcMA3gL4CU6AfMQLABQMMATgKZQCuTYtDjMAdIJx4ANPT7xCAIigtoU8TBL1ldeqEixECAELoswgsXJUejVhy5m+g-obG9GAI2mz5i1avXhoMdgAdhFlQMbFwjIgJoJgBLMABzEzRqIkULTm5UxwEhcIcJI0N+OBgAahgpGDcoBV5Pem9NP0DcFgBhfTC8QiJgfGi4xIpk63SrLIlbe0VGQvD+YDKKqrkajxUGuigAT38WGAAxdjBgKBjwZCYmOG39S+vtgB5Mf0I4MG3h6nftygBueg7PYwABqcAANjEgm0ABZwOKPAAqMBYAA9ZGAEBBDsdTucwPcbjARDAAJJgfzsWAYUgkgBKcnY4NgaIxWPgHwA2gBdfQ86gYRTI1ksTHYzldIzkylQL4wOIAMxYTBgdJJtkVypgiPh4JR6NF7KOJzOFyuN15AH5QRCoa1YfCwEjdSTpVSYAAyVUkzm2BkQJlQEmIzkABm53Mo+CF+rZ4swtle8rASpVAAU5ZqVWqcvws9rdbHDdjjXizQ8rTbIdC4QidTFwa6Ke6vTnfYJ-YGSZLCG7ZaY6ZHo7xO8zNkD9gBZZXxYLg8FIotinEm-GE25NmX6UgCmAxkXLiWGN4fTMprU5jXnlX1vUHo2400E83bSvTpiz5Dz50N+mesnNlAUYATK467PsIIAIz6GC1b2rWTqchOIAKvASDINyJK0jA-KAuBoIAEwwbaNaOo8SHgShaEoCSyGodoOiYcYPqRnhwIggAzMRcGyA6CIUXsVHaMgtGUfRSA6KJgmoQEQQYVhJAsZQbEQQALNxdq8Qh5F0dRIlVGJ1GSQZ0nNNCTHYbhWz4SCACsGmkfxumya08nMThrFqF5E4wJO0EYO+n7fgJLBCehnk+ZOREBTOc4LiFYU0SZoXiboEX4ZOXExR+cU6YZwlSSlRmFVRLmyBhynWcCk7qdlQXxbpBXJYlxnOS0vHpdV9l1blCUye1wSdVOABs+iBb1bXmZVjS+AquL6Iu97iryAA+K5ls+DyUJgAC2IAIDECoxMqECEMiXqwZp7TaYilBkIQ41fgut2mBMzBsBkWB7QdR0nfA2KImQ-CsAg7DACwmCYHAwDACS32HcdTBym95gfVY8O-UwUMw2QHgKRQcDYo934vRsXngmwzD+TAc0nJgnLCdyFAAPTMzAaaExA9AU7ATDRTTuL001DFMzArPs5z3OU0wWUC3TDPoSSDEkmVg0s8zHMQBA-BS7ztVy8AQuK8VZn2qL4sHLqXN0DzzDdQb9Oqxh6uHFbQA)

You can learn more about conditional types in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content)

Comment: Where can I learn these `infer` and more typescript stuff like this?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content Is a good starting point.